# Bind Pivot Header Template

Tags: data-binding, pivot, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I have a `Pivot Control` and three `PivotItems` added in `Blend`. Each `PivotItem` has a `ViewModel` as it's `DataContext`. Each `ViewModel` has a string property `Title`. I want to edit the `Header Template`, create a `TextBlock` and bind it's `Text` property to `Title`, but for some reason it doesn't work. I am sure it's because the `DataContext` of the `Header Template` is null, but I thought it would be inherited from the specific `PivotItem`. This is the `xaml` code for the Header Template.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <Grid Height="47" Width="354">
            <TextBlock Margin="8,0,64,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" FontSize="24" Foreground="Red"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>



    <controls:Pivot TitleTemplate="{StaticResource TitleTemplate}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem DataContext="{Binding Home, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Grid>
                <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HomeItemsPanel}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomeItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=listBox}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem Margin="0,8,0,1">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem DataContext="{Binding More, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

I want to create a more complex `Header Template` but for now I am testing if I can bind it, before proceeding on with something more than just a TextBlock. I know that I could use a `List` of `ViewModels` for the `PivotControl.ItemSource`, but then I would have to use a `DataTemplateSelector` and so on, and I don't want that.

So I guess my question is this, how can I make the HeaderTemplate inherit the DataContext of the according `PivotItem`?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using element binding?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work. You should write HeaderTemplate the following way:

```
<controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

Textblock will receive the binding from the PivotItem's Header property. For each PivotItem, you bind its Header:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="{Binding Title}">
    <Grid/>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

The only problem remains in binding each pivot item to its own data context. You can do that manually for each item with the following code:

```
<controls:PivotItem DataContext="{Binding Item1}" Header="{Binding Title}">
    <Grid/>
</controls:PivotItem>
<controls:PivotItem DataContext="{Binding Item2}" Header="{Binding Title}">
    <Grid/>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

Comment: I know what you're saying, but imagine I have an Image and a TextBox in the Header Template, then I wouldn't be able to bind them both. Anyway, in the end I used the ItemsSource property of the Pivot Control, a base ViewModel for my Pivot Items ViewModels, exposing all the common properties for the HeaderTemplate, and created a DataTemplateSelector, to choose between different ItemTemplates for my PivotItems. It took a while to understand, but the code looks quite clean and nice.